# Does anyone know why this sub omits my data?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to write this macro for a long time and I'm still constantly battling with this (in various categories actually) and now this macro kind of omits my data.

Here is the code (comments are used to describe what is what for me):

```
Sub testro()
    Const cSheet As String = "Procenty"
    Const cRange As String = "A2:D71"
    Const cel As Long = 4
    Const cCol As Variant = "A"


    Dim vntS As Variant
    Dim vntT As Variant
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    Dim emptyRow As Long

    Dim kom As Double, komz As Double, kredyt As Double
    Dim roz As Double, komr As Double, komn As Double
    Dim dz As Date, dw As Date

    vntS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet).Range(cRange).Value
    ReDim vntT(1 To 3 * UBound(vntS), 1 To cel + 1)
    kredyt = 0

    r = 1

    For i = 1 To UBound(vntS)

        dz = vntS(i, 1) 
        komz = vntS(i, 2)
        dw = vntS(i, 3)
        kom = vntS(i, 4)

        If komz > kom Then

            If CStr(vntT(r, 1)) = "" Then
               vntT(r, 1) = dz
               vntT(r, 2) = komz 'debt
            End If

            vntT(r, 3) = dw
            vntT(r, 4) = kom 'payment
            vntT(r, 5) = " komz>kom"

            r = r + 1

            komz = komz - kom

            vntT(r, 1) = dz
            vntT(r, 2) = komz ' Debt
            vntT(r, 3) = dw
            vntT(r, 4) = kom  '  payment
            vntT(r, 5) = " .. komz > kom"

        ElseIf komz < kom Then

            komn = kom - komz

            vntT(r, 1) = dz
            vntT(r, 2) = komz
            vntT(r, 3) = dw
            vntT(r, 4) = kom
            vntT(r, 5) = " .. A"

            r = r + 1

            vntT(r, 3) = dw
            vntT(r, 4) = komn  ' Overpaid
            vntT(r, 5) = " .. komz < kom"

            r = r + 1

        ElseIf komz = kom Then
            vntT(r, 1) = dz
            vntT(r, 2) = komz  ' debt
            vntT(r, 3) = dw
            vntT(r, 4) = kom   ' payment
            vntT(r, 5) = " .. komz = kom"

            r = r + 1

        End If


    Next

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet)
        emptyRow = .Columns(cCol).Find("*", , xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row + 1
        .Cells(emptyRow, cCol).Resize(UBound(vntT), UBound(vntT, 2)) = vntT
        .Cells(emptyRow, cCol) = kredyt
    End With
End Sub
```

Here I post a screenshots of data before using macro:
[image: before]

and after:
[image: after]

Here's a [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fSbm92R79kcklHz9YCclFDx_BBnBODUi) to my Google Drive with all screenshots including the one with what this macro should do (labeled good) link.

Color red is for data that's omitted (leftside columns) and the ones that should be assigned to it (in same row).

In the blue color section in the good screenshot you can see how it should be done.

Comment: Since we don't know what you **do** intend this macro to do, it would also be helpful if you could post what the _expected_ outcome was supposed to be.

Comment: I'm still not following what this is supposed to do (or what's wrong with the "after" output). Can you explain what you expect it to do and explain why what it's currently doing is wrong. "ate" isn't very descriptive.

Comment: Now I added link to my drive and explanations to screenshots

Comment: Every time you write data to `vntT` you increment `r` *except* for the last instance under `If komz > kom`  - is that intentional ?

Comment: Yes it moves to the next element in table ,the whole thing with this macro is that (in my opininon) while checking NOT printed elements in table (when all are printed) then it should go once again(so all printed data goes through ifs in macro) for all elements PRINTED